# Object is of type 'unknown' within .map?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a list of topics

```
const topics = getPromptCategories();
```

which looks like

```
[ { category: "cat1", attempts: 0 }, {category: "cat2", attempts: 0 } ]
```

So my interface is

```
interface topicInterface {
    category: string;
    attempts: number;
}
```

and I'm trying to derive a number of buttons out of the topics, so I'm doing this

```
const topicButtons = topics.map((topic) => {
    return <button>{topic.category}</button>;
});
```

but it's screaming at me about `Object is of type 'unknown'` at {topic.category}

If I add the interface to topic `topic: topicInterface` it's now telling me something different

```
Argument of type '(topic: topicInterface) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => Element'.
```

I'm new to typescript. What am I missing or overlooking?

Comment: You do not show us `getPromptCategories`. Does it return `topicInterface[]`?

Comment: My god, it wasn't. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show how are you adding the interface to topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it helps anyone else, @crashmstr pointed me in the right direction.

The issue was with my `getPromptCategories()` function as it wasn't returning `topicInterface[]`.

I went into my function and adjusted my code to reflect this

```
let out: topicInterface[] = Object.values(...);
return out;
```

And my topicButtons looks like

```
const topicButtons = topics.map((topic:topicInterface) => {
    return <button key={topic.category}>{topic.category}</button>;
});
```